# Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Here is my complete error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at View.templateEngine (/Users/shamoon/local/node/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view/view.js:133:38)
    at Function.compile (/Users/shamoon/local/node/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:65:17)
    at ServerResponse._render (/Users/shamoon/local/node/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:414:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/shamoon/local/node/lib/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:315:17)
    at /Users/shamoon/Sites/soldhere.in/app.js:26:7
    at callbacks (/Users/shamoon/local/node/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/Users/shamoon/local/node/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
```

My source code is also very simple:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', {
    layout: false
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    message : 'De groeten'
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

In my folder, I have ejs installed in node_modules which I got using `npm install ejs`.
[image] so my question is.. what gives? What am I doing wrong so that node can't find EJS when I clearly have it installed?

Thanks

Comment: did you install express globally? if i remember correctly i had problems when installing express globally and ejs locally. try to also install express in your project folder or ejs in the global module folder.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I ended up removing node_modules directory and doing a fresh install npm install -g.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

I had this exact same problem a couple of days ago and couldn't figure it out.  Haven't managed to fix the problem properly but this works as a temporary fix:

Go up one level (above app.js) and do `npm install ejs`. It will create a new node_modules folder and Express should find the module then.

Comment: `npm install ejs -g` might be a cleaner workaround. (`-g` for global install)

Comment: While deploying my app to Openshift, I had the same error and noticed I forgot to add a dependency to `ejs` in `packages.json`. Now it works fine (`npm install` was done automatically during the next restart).

Comment: I don't think you'd want to install a `node_module` globally, i've done the same before and it becomes a pain when you're deploying

Comment: I simply added the 'express' module as a dependency in my 'package.json' file and it started working. So make sure both 'ejs' and 'express' are mentioned as dependencies.

Comment: Obviously, I upvoted the main answer(er) but I also wanted to give credit to @Stephen Bugs Kamenar for suggesting the (-g) global install. I actually cheated and did both (lazy me) and it worked immediately upon restarting my app.

Answer (score 28):

## Install express locally

(`npm install express` while in the project's root directory)

---

Your project depends on both `express` and `ejs`, so you should list them both as dependencies in your `package.json`.

That way when you run `npm install` in you project directory, it'll install both `express` and `ejs`, so that `var express = require('express')` will be the **local** installation of express (which knows about the `ejs` module that you installed locally) rather than the global one, which doesn't.

In general it's a good idea to explicitly list all dependencies in your `package.json` even though some of them might already be globally installed, so you don't have these types of issues.

Answer (score 13):

Way back when the same issue happened with me.

Dependency was there for ejs in JSON file, tried installing it locally and globally but did not work.

Then what I did was manually adding the module by:

```
app.set('view engine','ejs'); 

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express);
```

Then it works.

Comment: this is especially true when you have express as a dependency in submodule

Comment: This makes it [ejs] discoverable when compiling (or simply bundling if not using typescript) your server to via webpack. (either copying over views to dist or further work is required to get it working; however.)

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'

Answer (score 11):

I my case, I just added ejs manually in **package.json**:

```
 {
   "name": "myApp"
   "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.12.2",
     "ejs": "^1.0.0"
   }
 }
```

And run **npm install** (may be you need run it with **sudo**)
Please note, that ejs looks views directory by default

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.  Once I set environment variable NODE_PATH to the location of my modules (/usr/local/node-v0.8.4/node_modules in my case) the problem went away.  P.S. NODE_PATH accepts a colon separated list of directories if you need to specify more than one.

Comment: This is super important and often missed, +1 to you Pete!

Comment: I had no NODE_PATH env var, so a simple `export NODE_PATH=.` worked for my project that has its dependencies under its own directory. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

I installed `ejs` using command `npm install ejs` in express directory level and this solved my problem.

i have install express using steps mention in express guide http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Answer (score 6):

After installing node express project you need to install the ejs or pug package for that

either you can try with node

```
npm install ejs 
npm install pug
```

or you can try with yarn

```
yarn add ejs
yarn add pug
```

globally or locally

Answer (score 5):

After you've installed Express V x.x.x
You need to choose an template view-engine. There are many really easy to learn. My personal go-to is [EJS](http://ejs.co/).

Other really great and easy to learn could be:

- [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [PUG (Former Jade)](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

To install EJS (And fix your error)
Run in root of your project:

```
npm install ejs
```

Or if you're using Yarn:

```
yarn add ejs
```

Next you'll need to require the module, so open up your file where you require express (usually app.js or server.js)

add below `var express = require('express');`

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
```

Answer (score 4):

Install it locally rather installing it globally. Then your project may be run on any machine without any error.I think its better.

```
npm install express --save
npm install ejs --save
```

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem. So i did the following and it worked for me.

solution:

1. run " npm init " in the project directory if not already done.
2. install ejs and express as follows:

npm install ejs --save
npm install express --save

by doing so it creates the required dependencies in the package.json file

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I debugged using node-inspector and saw that from the node_modules folder where the express source files were, ejs was not installed. So I installed it there and it worked.

`npm install -g ejs` didn't put it where I expected it to despite NODE_PATH being set to the same node_modules folder. Prob doing it wrong, just started with node.

Answer (score 3):

I installed both: express and  ejs with the option --save:

npm install ejs --save
 npm install express --save

This way express and ejs are dependecies package.json file.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling npm, express and ejs fixed my problem

This one worked for me,

1. On your terminal or cmd -> Go to your apps directory,
2. cd pathtoyourapp/AppName
3. rerun your 'npm install'
4. rerun your 'npm install express'
5. rerun your 'npm install ejs'

after that, the error was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1**

See `npm ls | grep ejs` at root level of your project to check if you have already added `ejs` `dependency` to your project.

If not, add it as `dependencies` to your project. *(I prefer adding dependency to `package.json` instead of `npm install`ing the module.)*

eg.

```
{                                                                                                      
  "name": "musicpedia",                                                                                
  "version": "0.0.0",                                                                                  
  "private": true,                                                                                     
  "scripts": {                                                                                         
    "start": "node ./bin/www"                                                                          
  },                                                                                                   
  "dependencies": {                                                                                    
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",                                                                          
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",                                                                         
    "debug": "~2.2.0",                                                                                 
    "express": "~4.13.4",                                                                              
    "jade": "~1.11.0",                                                                                 
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",                                                                                                                                                            
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",                                                                                
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"                                                                          
  }                                                                                                    
}
```

**STEP 2 download the dependencies**

```
npm install
```

**STEP 3 check ejs module**

```
$ npm ls | grep ejs
musicpedia@0.0.0 /Users/prayagupd/nodejs-fkers/musicpedia
├── ejs@1.0.0
```

Comment: Great! Did all the above, but didn't run npm install again. Thanks.

Comment: are you saying `npm install` did not work after adding `"ejs": "^1.0.0"`? If so, remove that line and install another way as `npm install ejs` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs. It should add a `ejs: latest version` to package.json

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency in `package.json` and then run `npm install`

```
    {
  ...
  ... 
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "ejs": "*",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think ejs template engine is not properly installed on your machine. 
You just install the template engine using npm

```
npm install ejs --save
```

then include the following code in app.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue it resolve after installing the express in my project directory. previously  i install it in global scope with -g option with npm install command.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a stupid mistake- it was a typo in the middleware. I wrote `app.set('view engine', 'ejs.');` the dot caused the error. I installed ejs and express locally

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was no silly syntax error, but same error arised.
I had installed ejs and ejs-mate globally. I installed it locally and found my error resolved.

Answer (score 1):

kindly ensure that your dependencies in your package.json files are up to date. Try reinstalling them one at a time after also ensuring that your NPM is the latest version (up-to-date). It worked for me. I advise you to run `npm install` for the packages(thats what worked in my own case after it refused to work because I added the dependencies manually).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure all dependencies are installed. `npm install`

I was making a quick app for myself and I had forgotten to add express. Threw the above error.

Answer (score 1):

I face same error for ejs, then i just run `node install ejs`
This will install ejs again.

and then also run `npm install` to install node_modules again.
That's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after I forgot to install ejs before the first time I ran my app. For some reason ejs was not being seen after installing it later. I found a quick, clean, and effective solution to this problem which was to reinstall express by running `npm uninstall express` then `npm install express` in the local directory before restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

> `npm i ejs --force`

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Installing express locally solved my same problem.
npm i express --save

Comment: Welcome on the SO! Why and how? Express is by default locally installed for development.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and tried a few of the given solutions but it still didn't work. all i did was to run the "npx yarn" command in the root folder of my project and that was it.

Answer (score 1):

you must have

```
const ejs = require('ejs')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

and then in the terminal

```
npm install ejs --save
```

resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just uninstall then install ejs again.

```
npm uninstall ejs
```

then

```
npm install ejs
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install ejs --save` worked for me ! ✅

On goormIDE, I had this file configuration :

- **container**

  - main.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json
  - node_modules
  - views

    - *home.ejs*

In my main.js file, I also had this route

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("home.ejs");
})
```

`npm install ejs -g` didn't add the corresponding dependency within the package.json.
`npm install ejs --save` did. I executed the command line from the container directory. Manually it could have been added into the package.json with : 
**

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.0.2",}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I tried every command in the answers and everywhere else and nothing worked. Eventually, I went to another project of mine, copied the `ejs` folder from `node_modules`, then pasted it in my current broken project, after that everything worked.

It's worth noting that I looked in my `node_modules/ejs` folder before and I couldn't find any files other than a `package.json`, `license`, etc., no `lib` folder, or any `.js` files and running `yarn install`, `yarn remove ejs`/`yarn add ejs`/`yarn add ejs --save` did nothing to fix it.