# Node js , Error: can not find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

Here is the error which I get when I run nodejs app.js

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'share'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/quicksilver/project/master/app.js:3:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I am repeatedly getting this error :
I have already done npm install -g share  several times ,but it has been no use.

```
var express = require('express')
var sharejs = require('share')
var connect = require('connect')
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

//var zmq = require('zmq');
var app = express();
app.set('view options', {layout: false});
var problem={};
var sharejs_server;
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsconfig.json');

locomotive.boot('.', app.settings.env, function(err, app) {
var options = {};
if (err) { throw err; }
options.db = app.locals.db;
sharejs_server = sharejs.server.attach(app, options);
app.listen(app.locals.port, app.locals.ip, function () {
     var addr = this.address();
     console.log('listening on %s:%d', addr.address, addr.port);
}); 
});
```

Comment: From the [readme for share on npm](https://npmjs.org/package/share): "Welcome. So you know, this code might spontaneously catch fire".

Comment: @TrevorSenior: I don't know about the code,but I want to bang my head against the wall.

Comment: Maybe try an older version. They say it's become more unstable over time.

Comment: have you tried the npm link command? i think some globals can't be accessed

Comment: Why are you using `-g`? Just `npm install share` should be sufficient. Global installations are in general a bad idea for anything except installing utility applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754799/error-cannot-find-module-ejs)