# Error: Cannot find module 'ejs' even though it's listed in package.json

Tags: node.js, express, package.json

My application is not loading the 'EJS' module when I try and invoke routing in my `app.js` file and I'd like to know why.

My question is very [similar in scope to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754799/error-cannot-find-module-ejs), but it has some additional wrinkles to it that were not addressed in the answers there so I thought I'd turn this into a new question entirely.

If I start a very basic `app.js` file like this that calls `ejs` it works as expected and raises no errors.

**APP.JS:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello World");
    }).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("The port is now listening at 3000");
  });
```

However, once I modify `app.js` to use routes to render a view I get the error message in the title.

The following script provides the error:

**APP.JS:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var root = require('./routes/index');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(root);

app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("The port is now listening at 3000");
});

module.exports = app;
```

My index.js file that I use to establish the route looks like this:

**INDEX.JS:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index', {
  pageTitle: 'The Formula Generator',
  pageDescription: 'Easily manage and store your supplement formulas',
  pageID: 'home' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

EJS is correctly loaded in my package.json like so:

**PACKAGE.JSON:**

```
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "~1.15.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.2.0",
"ejs": "^2.5.5",
"express": "~4.14.0",
"mongodb": "^2.2.16",
"monk": "^3.1.3",
"morgan": "~1.7.0",
"serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
 },
```

It's also installed in my node_modules folder as well.

My file structure currently looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var root = require('./routes/index');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

root(app); // pass app to index

app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("The port is now listening at 3000");
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var controller = function(app){
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
      pageTitle: 'The Formula Generator',
      pageDescription: 'Easily manage and store your supplement formulas',
      pageID: 'home' });
    });
};
module.exports = controller;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.2.6",
    "ejs": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sumeet, thank you for the answer.  However, I'm still getting the same error message.  I'm beginning to think the issue is with a system variable on my computer that isn't set correctly, since this really seems to be a simple program that ought to work.  Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: npm install ejs  did it install ejs for you?@JonathanBechtel

Comment: can you show us error stack trace what you are getting @JonathanBechtel

Comment: I just did an npm install express in my root directory and that did the trick for me.  I'm not sure why this was the cause of the issue, since I ran express with "Hello World" and that did the trick, but that solved the problem.

Comment: Great @JonathanBechtel

Answer (score 1):

Install express on root of the project .

```
npm install express --save
```